# Nginx virtual host error duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/vhosts/

Tags: wordpress, nginx

After I added [add this Wordpress W3 Total configuration](http://pastebin.com/xB8DnPAN) to my Apache + Nginx VPS vhosts (which is located at /etc/nginx/vhosts/mysite.com), it gives me following error. (In Nginx Admin when the server rebooting)

> 2014/01/25 17:08:03 [emerg] 640#0: duplicate location "/" in
>   /etc/nginx/vhosts/mysite.com:54

- my nginx main configuration file:- http://pastebin.com/jHtG1Hax
- my vhost default configuration file :- http://pastebin.com/pQMZutL0

W3 total configuration:- http://pastebin.com/xB8DnPAN

How do I fix this issue? Any help really appreciated.

Comment: the error was about `/etc/nginx/vhosts/mysite.com` is that the file you shared?

Comment: I added w3total cache configuration file codes to this VPS /etc/nginx/vhosts/mysite.com site nginx configuration file. After that I receive that error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you have the same location defined twice, just like the error says, you need to remove this block

```
location / {
            try_files /wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/${host}${cache_uri}_index.html $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
}
```

and then delete this in the other file

```
try_files $uri @backend;
```

and put this instead

```
try_files /wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/${host}${cache_uri}_index.html $uri @backend;
```

here's the `@backend` location

```
location @backend {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
}
```

Any other location should just use this same proxy location, and for the `~\.php` I think it can be replaced with something like this

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files @backend =404;
}
```

Comment: @ Mohammad AbuShady>>>. Thanks Mohammad your support. I'll try this method. I don't know what's the @backend. I have a manage vps. They installed apach and nginx. Is it OK if I remove @backend?

Comment: Now Nginx CP giving me this error and VPS refuse to boot. [emerg] 640#0: directive "try_files" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/vhosts/mydomain.com:33

Comment: @ Mohammad AbuShady If I use this code, nothing issue. :D http://pastebin.com/gB8Ju9Ey But it doesn't have @backend part. So it will cause any issue?

Comment: lol just like it says, i forgot to put a `;` at the end of the line, ill fix my answer

Comment: could you check the error log ? I'd say the issue is in the `@backend` location

Comment: Nginx load wp-admin, but when I navigate to "new posts, edit posts" etc pages, it gives nginx "502 band gateway" error. Looks like frontend OK. Backend This is the nginx Vhost error log:- http://pastebin.com/YRBBnGv3

Comment: This VPS uses fcgi as a PHP 5 Handler and use EasyApache. When I'm searching .sock file in the VPS file system, I can't find anything similar to the .sock extension. Could you please give me an suggestion to fix this matter?

Comment: You're using `fastcgi`, but your w3cache config is assuming you are using `php5-fpm`, I think probably `fastcgi` is using port 9000, Inside the w3total config file replace `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` with `fastcgi_pass http://localhost:9000`

Comment: After added `fastcgi_pass http://localhost:9000` it gives me  `invalid host in upstream error `http://localhost:9000``. In nginx admin and refuse to boot the VPS. Then I changed itThen I used  `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` after that i again face 502 bad gateway error. :( I can see this log in the nginx vhost error log `*156 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client`

Comment: Then I added 9000 to CSF allow TPC (TCP_IN and TCP_OUT) in /etc/csf/csf.conf file, but no luck.

Comment: try `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 9000` to make sure it's listening on there

Comment: It doesn't give any response. Once I press enter key, it again shows `root@host [~]#`.

Comment: try `sudo service php5-fcgi status`, if it says it's off run `sudo service php5-fcgi start` , not sure though if it's `php5-fcgi` or `php5-cgi`, you can try both

Comment: When I'm running that command, it give me " `php5-fcgi: unrecognized service` and `php5-cgi: unrecognized service` ". When I'm searching `fpm` i can see `fpm_sockets.h` and `fpm_sockets.c` files. They are located in `/home/cpeasyapache/src/php-5.4.24/sapi/fpm/fpm/` directory. In `Configure PHP and suEXEC` I can see PHP 5 Handler `fcgi` and `Apache suEXEC` ON. PHP version 5.

Comment: Mohammad, it giving "php5-fpm: unrecognized service". :(

Comment: what distro of linux do you have ?

Comment: CENTOS 6.4 i686 virtuozzo. Frontend Nginx (Nginx Admin v4. 4 add-on), backend Apache (2.2.26) with EasyApache.

Comment: wait, if you're really using apache as an php interpreter then we're looking in the wrong place, you wouldn't have fpm nor fcgi, this is why the code used `@backend`, that's where it's proxying to apache, what port is apache listening to ?

Comment: When I run `netstat -lp` this is the output. http://pastebin.com/RnRPwwMs. But my `httpd.conf` has following listener ports. http://pastebin.com/qAjjbXLM

Comment: inside `@backend` replace  `proxy_pass` with `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081`, reload nginx and hopefully it would work

Comment: You mean something like this? Change the W3 total page cache code like this http://pastebin.com/PgSz8L6M and remove this code http://pastebin.com/eaJfxwfF

Comment: let me modify my answer

Comment: Mohammad, my host already has this code http://pastebin.com/DeLBTbq4 (something like you mentioned). Therefore, adding a similar code right after the W3 total page cache try files code, may not cause any conflict? Default vhost configuration:- http://pastebin.com/pQMZutL0

Comment: yea it's working, I don't understand why it's returning a 502 then.

Comment: It happened If I used this code http://pastebin.com/JAAr81xW. Without that code, no issue.

Comment: this part is totally wrong, this part should be removed, you are not using php5-fpm.

Comment: Thank you so much Mohammad your support. I really appreciate your support. If I can, I'll definitely vote your answer.